# Check if a given string, which only contains round/square/curly brackets, has its open brackets closed by the same type of brackets on python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

I hope not to sound very weird here, basically, suppose that you have the following strings:

```
s1 = '{[]}'

s2 = '[(])'

s3 = '()[]{}'
```

And you want to build a program/function that verifies that such strings are `'valid'` if:

> **Open brackets are closed by the same type of brackets**

So the output for the cases above would be:

```
theFunction(s1)
```

> **valid**

```
theFunction(s2)
```

> **NOT valid**

```
theFunction(s3)
```

> **valid**

I was thinking of building it like this:

```
def theFunction(s):
   the_dic = {'(':')',
              '[':']',
              '{':'}',
              }

   if any(s.startswith(ch) for ch in the_dic.keys()):
      for char in s:
         #...?
         result = 'valid'
   else: 
      result = 'NOT valid'

   return result
```

May I get some help here?

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list for open brackets.

Iterate each char of the given string and if you have open bracket push bracket to list.

If you have close bracket pop from list and if there is a missmatch of bracket type return invalid.

At last chack if there any bracket in list - if any you have invalid otherwise your string is correct